# Making BI publisher report on more than one instance in oracle

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I have 50 databases all connected by oracle grid control(Enterprise manager) and each database is represented by exactly one instance...I want to make one report using BI publisher which includes: 
1- Name of each database that is listed in the grid control
2- number of tablespaces of each instance that is listed in the grid control

EDIT : It's not reliable to make 50 datasources, so I'm not asking for how to make one report with more than datasource.

Comment: Can you create a view in one of the instances the links/unions all the data together, then base the report on that.

Comment: That's a good idea

Comment: But this means that I should create 50 links which is not advisable...but still a good solution